# What does this refer to and why?

Tags: javascript

In this example:

```
var A = {test: 1, foo: function() { return this.test }}
```

Why `A.foo()` returns `1` (at least in node.js)? I thought `this` will be bound to external caller `this`, no?

Comment: Why this refers to the object? I don't exactly get the reason behind asking the why...

Comment: Why = what is the rationale, rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does this refer to in a javascript private method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259721/what-does-this-refer-to-in-a-javascript-private-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `A.foo()`, `this` within `foo()` is set to the object `A`, as that is what you called the function on.  Therefore, `this.test` has a value of `1`.

You can change what `this` is referenced to using [`.call()` or `.apply()`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx).

```
A.foo.call(newThisValue);
```

As for why... this gives you great flexibility.  You may have a function that acts on `this` to do something, and the way JavaScript is built allows you to apply that function to any `object` in a specific way.  It is a bit hard to describe, but it does come in handy in situations such as [inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html).  See also:  http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_call_and_apply

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript [whenever you call a function](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3) using `obj.method()` notation, `this` will be bound to `obj`.

You can work around this by splitting the call into two separate steps:

```
var f = A.foo;
f(); // "this" will not be A in this case.
```

Or, abusing the comma operator:

```
(17, x.f)()
```